# How to create new session in tmux, run command there and keep it alive and detached from command line?

Tags: tmux

I want to run tmux, create some session inside, run some command, then detach from tmux and then be able to re-attach to tmux and see remaining command output.

This looks normal operation, but I want to do it from command line.

If I do

```
tmux -d 'ls'
```

I can't go back and see `ls` output.

Answer (score 3):

One of:

```
tmux new -d \; send ls Enter
tmux new -d \; setw remain-on-exit on \; respawnw -k ls
tmux new -d 'ls; sleep 1000000'
```

Of course if your program doesn't exit on its own (say top rather than ls), you can just do:

```
tmux new -d top
```